# Building VSIX project in Release does not create a VSIX file anymore, just a DLL

Tags: dll, build, release, vsix

I think the title is pretty clear. I always build in Release mode and upload the created VSIX file to the VS Marketplace.

Since today, it just creates a .dll file when I build in Release mode, no VSIX is generated. Also,in Debug I cannot set break points anymore, symbols won't load.

After reverting the commit (5 lines of code) to the previous version the problem still occurs.

I have no idea what could have caused this. Anyone experienced this before and what can I try to resolve this?

Edit:

This shows up in the build log, can this be the cause?

```
warning CS1762: A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'EnvDTE, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because of an indirect reference to that assembly created by assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly
```

When I set the Embed Interop Types property to true on the EnvDTE assembly I get `service can not be embedded` errors throughout the package code.

I tried creating new VSIX projects or opening older ones, no issues there, it creates a .VSIX file when building in release mode. Comparing the CSPROJ files and configuration shows no difference.

Comment: Without some specific details (version of VS, and a detailed build log), it's impossible to know what may have changed. Try creating/building a new VSSDK package, and verify if the .VSIX is generated. If so, cross check your project file and diagnostic build logs with the working project.

Comment: Do you have any link to a repository when we can take a look at your code? I think I solved this problem once but I need to see the code to remember because it was a long time ago

Comment: Gents, I fixed it. For some reason the VSBuildTools dependency got messed up, did a propper check on the csproj and fixed it there + updated through NuGet manager. In the detailed build log I also noticed nothing was written to bin/release, and compared to the build log of my other extension I could figure out what steps were not executed. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: The error I mentioned has nothing to do with this and is a differenct case.